# Safe way to resolve Windows files owner inconsistencies

Tags: windows, security, windows-11

I just found out that I have a mix of security properties inconsistencies on my files.
The desktop was build afresh 2 yrs ago but with Win 10. It was upgraded to Win 11. Also one disk (**not system**) is from previous desktops (probably 4-5 different Windows 7-10 installations and upgrades).

So I have **owners** as SYSTEM, Administrators, (me), Unknown Users with a long strings after name like `S-1-5-21-1???898413-1596???624-59???253-????` (*I inserted `?`*) etc.

This machine is a single user but I might use IIS in future or some other systems that create own users.

Is there a simple cheat sheet - how to safely override / make things consistent without bringing the whole OS down?

Can I just override `owner` of everything with `Administrators`?

Comment: Unknown users from previous installation will appear using the USID of the user. You can The actual value of the USID can be used to identify what type of account it is.  You have not provided enough information to answer your question.  Can you replace the owner of which files exactly?  The default permissions on system files is correct and SHOULD NOT be changed.

Comment: Based on you saying you transferred the drive from many other OS upgrades and it's not a system disk, etc. you can likely right click the drive | properties | security | Edit | then highlight the accounts with SIDs only and select remove. From security | Advanced | the Owner: will likely be SYSTEM which is the computer root account it is attached. The owner here and the accounts with ACL NTFS permissions are two different things though. The owner should be SYSTEM

Comment: @Ramhound - i want to replace all or most of the owners without picking it one by one (I have 8 TBs of data). So If I leave SYSTEM intact but replace everything else with myself or Administrator group - would it be ok?

Comment: @Chunky - I am talking about "owner" specifically not ACL..

Comment: @BoppityBop - The owner of a folder is part of the ACL.  You can safety remove any user that cannot be identified from the ACL.

Comment: There isn't an automatic or one-line command to "repair" Windows file permissions. That question has been asked before and answered. Windows comes in a default state, but there are good reasons for it to change to adjust to the actual needs of the system. For this reason, any automatic repair is more likely to destroy the systems usability. The only way to repair is to use your knowledge of the system and its history and purpose and make necessary corrections manually.